# What version of ant-salesforce.jar am I using?

Tags: ant, migration-tool

Is there a way for me to determine what `ant-salesforce.jar` file I'm using? My client uses TeamCity which internally uses the JAR file provided by Salesforce. We're trying to determine what Salesforce version it's at.

We were specifically trying to determine if it's later than 35.0 or not, for using the `testLevel` param. But TeamCity seems to ignore any params it doesn't understand - basically `testLevel='RunLocalTests'` did not run any test classes; but we're still trying to find the exact version.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found some custom way, how you can detect your API version of `ant-salesforce.jar`. `jar` is an archive file, so it is possible to restore this file into components. Use `WinRar` or another archiver-program to do it.

After restoring you will see the following structure of folders:

[image]

open next file `META-INF\maven\com.force.api\force-wsc\pow.properties` with any text editor. and here you will see **version**

```
#Generated by Maven
#Wed Dec 14 12:53:11 PST 2016
version=39.0.0
groupId=com.force.api
artifactId=force-wsc
```

For example, I have 39.0 API version of ant-salesfore. This is Spring '17

Comment: I just did that myself. Cheers! I was looking at the `pom.xml` which had similar information